# CMake: Adding IDE visibility for common headers in a multi-library/binary C++ project

Tags: c++, cmake, ide, header-files

NOTE: This question regards getting headers to show up in IDEs, *not* just getting them to be included in the build. The latter is not a concern here.

I have a project that looks basically like this, and I'm trying to convert its build system to CMake:

```
project/
  include/
     common/
        common1.hpp
        common2.hpp
        ...
     lib1/
        file1_1.hpp
        file1_2.hpp
        ...
     lib2/
        file2_1.hpp
        file2_2.hpp
        ...
     ...
     bin1/
        ...
  src/
     CMakeLists.txt (project)
     lib1/
        file1_1.cpp
        file1_2.cpp
        ...
        CMakeLists.txt (add_library)
     lib2/
        file2_1.cpp
        file2_2.cpp
        ...
        CMakeLists.txt (add_library)
     ...
     bin1/
        main.cpp
        ...
        CMakeLists.txt (add_executable)
```

In each leaf directory's `CMakeLists.txt`, I'm including the corresponding header files in the `add_library()` or `add_executable()` command, for maximum IDE compatibility.

My question is: How do I wrangle CMake to get the non-library-specific headers under `common/` to show up in IDEs as well?

My current plan is to just assign each of them to the library/binary that makes the most use of them, but this is unsatisfying. I'm also not sure what this will end up doing to the project structure presentation in various IDEs; it would be best if it mirrored the physical layout of the files somewhat.

Note that I'm currently stuck using CMake 2.8.12.2, so many 3.x-only features will not be an option for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this is basically a duplicate of [QtCreator CMake project - how to show all project files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28384935/qtcreator-cmake-project-how-to-show-all-project-files)

Following the [accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33630604/3171290) there, I created a subdirectory in the source tree with only a CMakeLists.txt, which contains something like the following:

```
set(HEADERS
   ${MY_INCLUDE_DIR}/common/common1.hpp
   ${MY_INCLUDE_DIR}/common/common2.hpp
   ...
)

add_custom_target(common SOURCES ${HEADERS})
```

The keyword `SOURCES` in the `add_custom_target()` command tells CMake that these are code files that are not directly built but need to be added to the project for IDE visibility.

Documentation: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html